# What is the exact function of the piece of code given below?

Tags: c, arrays

What is the exact function of

> > int a[20] = {0.0};

I came across this on the internet

Comment: @ChrisHayes All elements are being set to 0...is it a shorthand for that?

Answer (score 1):

yes, since its integer int a[20] = {0}, sets the initialize the array elements to zero. @ChrisHayes is right always execute things and see it. Happy learning

Answer (score 1):

```
int a[20] = {0.0};
```

It initialize all the elements of `a` to `0`. Note that `0.0` is `double`, so there is a type conversion. A better equivalent form is:

```
int a[20] = {0};
```

Or even simpler:

```
int a[20] = {};
```

But that's it, omitting the `{}` like this: `int a[20]` would be different, the elements will be left un-initialized.

Comment: I'm not sure I really care for the last form.  For the effort of adding a single zero it is self-documenting.

Comment: @Duck I think that's only a difference in coding style. After all, even with `int a[20] = {0};`, the left 19 elements are initialized to `0`, even if it's not done explicitly.

Comment: @YuHao int a[20] = {}; would also initialize it to 0?

Comment: @anakin Yes. As another example, `int a[20] = {1};` would initialize the first element to `1` and the rest to `0`.

Answer (score -1):

In my case this code initialize all elements to zero its equal to

```
a[20] = {};
```

Output

```
0,0,0,0,0.....
```

for example to initialize  the first element to another values and the rest of array to zero use :

```
a[20] = {1};
```

Output

```
1,0,0,0.....
```